# In pandas, how do I open a txt file where each line is formatted like a json object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file where each line looks like this

```
{"key1":"1", "key2":"2", "key3":"3"}
{"key1":"4", "key2":"5", "key3":"6"}
...
```

I am wondering how to open in pandas such that

the repeating keys are pandas column heads, and the values for each line have their own row. So the desired result is

```
key1 | key2 | key3 |
1  |    2    |  3    |
4  |  5      |  6    |
```

I tried using pandas.read_json using every option for the orient parameter, but each one gives and error of `ValueError: Trailing data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.read_json` with `lines=True` para to read the file as a json object per line.

```py
pd.read_json('file_name', orient='records', lines=True)
   key1  key2  key3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
```